# Profiling Vim startup time

Tags: debugging, optimization, vim, profiling

I’ve got a lot of plugins enabled when using Vim – I have collected plugins over the years.  I’m a bit fed up with how long Vim takes to start now, so I’d like to profile its startup and see which of the many plugins I have are responsible.

Is there any way to profile Vim’s startup or script-running?  Ideally I’d like to know how long Vim spends in each Vim script it loads.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

If you're using Vim 7.2.269 or later, then there's the --startuptime option you can use.

```
vim --startuptime vim.log
```

from the help (`vim -h`):

```
--startuptime <file> Write startup timing messages to <file>
```

Comment: And as of patch 7.2.286, there's no equal sign needed.  "vim --startuptime vim.log"

Comment: if you want it to just print it, try `vim --startuptime /dev/stdout +qall`

Comment: @barraponto There's also `time vim +q` if you only want to time vim's startup as a whole.

Comment: On my terminal there is a significant difference between `vim --startuptime /dev/stdout +qall` and `vim --startuptime vim.log +qall; cat vim.log`.

Comment: @CapiEtheriel This would be cool but unfortunately it gives a useless report as this quits before loading any plugins.

Answer (score 62):

I created [this](https://github.com/hyiltiz/vim-plugins-profile) Github project in order to better answer your question. Basically, it calls `vim`'s built-in profiler with appropriate flags and options, then sums up the timing for each function calls for every plugins, which is not obvious (but important) from the raw `vim --profile` output. Bash, Python, R, Ruby and Perl are supported (you don't need to install anything since you most likely have one of those already) for creating the profiling results.

You will get a result figure like this:

[image: vim-plugins-profile figure]

Along with text output like this:

```
Generating vim startup profile...    
Parsing vim startup profile...     
Crunching data and generating profile plot ...    

Your plugins startup profile graph is saved     
as `profile.png` under current directory.    

==========================================    
Top 10 Plugins That Slows Down Vim Startup    
==========================================    
   1    105.13  "vim-colorschemes"    
   2    42.661  "vim-easytags"    
   3    31.173  "vim-vendetta"    
   4    22.02   "syntastic"    
   5    13.362  "vim-online-thesaurus"    
   6    7.888   "vim-easymotion"    
   7    6.931   "vim-airline"    
   8    6.608   "YankRing.vim"    
   9    5.266   "nerdcommenter"    
  10    5.017   "delimitMate"    
==========================================    
Done!
```

Comment: Very nice! checked my vim too, > 60 ms ^.^ This can help you quickly find the package that slows you down a lot (which in my case is still nothing :D)

Answer (score 49):

You can use vim own profiling mechanism:

```
vim --cmd 'profile start profile.log' \
    --cmd 'profile func *' \
    --cmd 'profile file *' \
    -c 'profdel func *' \
    -c 'profdel file *' \
    -c 'qa!'
```

After running the above you will find a file called profile.log in the current directory with all required information. To get per-script information table similar to already present per-function one, use (after opening this file in vim):

```
" Open profile.log file in vim first
let timings=[]                      
g/^SCRIPT/call add(timings, [getline('.')[len('SCRIPT  '):], matchstr(getline(line('.')+1), '^Sourced \zs\d\+')]+map(getline(line('.')+2, line('.')+3), 'matchstr(v:val, ''\d\+\.\d\+$'')'))
enew                            
call setline('.', ['count total (s)   self (s)  script']+map(copy(timings), 'printf("%5u %9s   %8s  %s", v:val[1], v:val[2], v:val[3], v:val[0])'))
```

It will be unsorted, but you can always use built-in `:sort` command if number of scripts is too large.

Comment: I didn't realise vim had a profiling command, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Benj It can be disabled. According to the doc you either require vim with huge set of features or self-compiled one where you explicitly enabled +profile without enabling this set.

Comment: Would +3 this if I could. It helped me track down a check in `dbext.vim`, which was taking over three seconds https://github.com/johnsyweb/dotfiles/commit/09c3001

Comment: @ZyX, How can I do this in windows shell (gvim)? It doesn't work in windows gvim. I inserted this command in windows shell `gvim --cmd 'profile start profile.log' --cmd 'profile func *' --cmd 'profile file *' -c 'profdel func *' -c 'profdel file *' -c 'qa!'` It does create a lot of empty files in vim.

Comment: @Remonn Use double quotes. Or bash from cygwin.

Answer (score 22):

Based on the work done by [@hyiltiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33194019/1043187) that depends on R, I made a [Python version](https://github.com/bchretien/vim-profiler) of the profiler, since this is more often available on a system that R.

It's also slightly easier to extend, thus the features are:

- Automatic detection of the plugin folder,
- **Bar plot** thanks to matplotlib,
- Run the analysis over several executions to get the **average/standard deviation**,
- Supports both **vim** and **neovim**,
- Can be used with a **full vim command** to test lazy-loading features, opening a file with a specific filetype etc.,
- Export result to a csv file.

The output is similar to what vim-plugins-profile provides:

```
$ vim-profiler.py -p nvim

Running nvim to generate startup logs... done.
Loading and processing logs... done.
Plugin directory: /home/user/.config/nvim/plugged
=====================================
Top 10 plugins slowing nvim's startup
=====================================
1         3.326   vim-fugitive
2         2.936   tcomment_vim
3         2.315   vim-hybrid
4         1.751   lightline.vim
5         0.959   vim-sneak
6         0.943   supertab
7         0.542   vim-surround
8         0.536   fzf.vim
9         0.450   fzf
10        0.434   auto-pairs
=====================================
```

[image: vim-profiler]

Comment: This plugin does not work for neovim windows. The error message is `No plugin found`.

Answer (score 21):

You could run `vim -V`, pipe the output through a utility that adds timestamps and analyze the output. This command lines does this, e.g.:

```
vim -V 2>&1 | perl -MTime::HiRes=time -ne 'print time, ": ", $_' | tee vilog
```

You might have to blindly type <kbd>:q</kbd> to get back to your prompt. Afterwards, you should find the file `vilog` in your current directory with hires timestamps at the beginning of each line.

If you can do with a granularity of a second, you can do this:

```
vim -V 2>&1 | perl -ne 'print time, ": ", $_' | tee vilog
```

Comment: Did you know the "perl -n" does the while (<>) {} for you.

Comment: Now that you mention it: yes, I did. I'm going to edit the answer to get shorter commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

I refined the vim -V [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688249/292408) by innaM to show the delta time:

```
vim -V 2>&1 | perl -MTime::HiRes=time -ne '$a = time unless defined $a; print time - $a, ": ", $_' | tee vilog
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're loading your plugins from a .vimrc file, what you could do is put a `q` on some line part way through the file to make it quit so you can use a process timer, like the unix `time` command.  More thoroughly, this would look like:

1. backup existing `.vimrc` file
2. comment out all but a select number of plugins
3. insert a `q` line
4. call `time vim` repeteadly and average
5. restore backup

This is not elegant but I think it will get the job done.

Comment: Hmm, not bad in a pinch.  I've already got my vimrc split into lots of seperate files so shouldn't be too hard to automate.

Answer (score 2):

It can be convenient to trace the `--startime` when opening a particular file

```
gvim app/views/layouts/application.html.erb --startuptime time.log
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin to profile the vim start-up time.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2915

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a bash `time` command that can be used like so:

```
time vim
```

**EDIT**: Doesn't include the scripts start up time. Use @jamessan suggestion instead.

Comment: Yes, there is but that would only tell you how long vim took to both open and close, not how long it took to parse each script.

Answer (score 0):

Another command line util to profile vim startup time written in go.

From the GitHub page:

> $ vim-startuptime

By default, it tries to run vim and :quit immediately 10 times, collects the results and outputs a summary of them to stdout.

https://github.com/rhysd/vim-startuptime