# VIM: dynamic runtimepath per module.vim and slow startup

Tags: vim

I'm using VIM 7.1 on Debian. I have 9 plugins that I load via pathogen.vim. It takes around 8 sec's to load which is quite slow since this is in non-GUI/xterm mode. I ran vim -V and it shows that each module is being searched for in multiple directories.

Initially, ftoff.vim, debian.vim and other "system" related .vim files are searched for in ~/.vim/ and then in /usr/share/vim/vim71/ - I fixed this by moving my .vimrc to .vim/vimrc and: export VIM=/root/.vim, within .vimrc i did a set runtimepath=/usr/share/vim/vim71

But now, when the modules load, they alter this runtimepath and when pathogen loads it's even worse. Is there a way to specify a hash of module-name to dirPath so that this error prone lookup is avoided? Or a way to manually specify runtimepath on a per module basis within vimrc?

Here is an example of my runtimepath after pathogen loads my modules. Obviously, any further loading of a module invovles searching all those pathnames before locating the right path.

runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/Align294,~/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim_-_Elegant_buffer_explorer,~/.vim/bu
ndle/The_NERD_Commenter,~/.vim/bundle/The_NERD_tree,~/.vim/bundle/pathogen,~/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-mw-utils,
/.vim/bundle/tlib,~/.vim/bundle/snipMate,~/.vim/bundle/SuperTab,~/.vim/bundle/surround,~/.vim/bundle/taglist
~/.vim/bundle/Align294,~/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim_-_Elegant_buffer_explorer,~/.vim/bundle/pathogen,~/.vim
bundle/snipMate,~/.vim/bundle/SuperTab,~/.vim/bundle/surround,~/.vim/bundle/taglist,~/.vim/bundle/The_NERD_C
mmenter,~/.vim/bundle/The_NERD_tree,~/.vim/bundle/tlib,~/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-manager,~/.vim/bundle/vim-add
n-manager-known-repositories,~/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-mw-utils,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/u
r/share/vim/vim71,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/bundle/snipMate/after,~/.vi
/after,~/.vim/bundle/snipMate/after

Comment: By the way, 1) why do use pathogen if you have vim-addon-manager? 2) I do not understand the second paragraph. Could you write it clearer (for example, write a script that will do with my ~/.vim* the same thing you have done with yours)?

Answer (score 2):

I use vim-addon-manager and have 33 paths in `rtp`, but it takes around 0.7-0.8 seconds to start and immideately close vim (with `vim -c 'qa!'`), so the problem is either one of the plugins or your system. To check how long it takes to load each plugin, try the following script:

```
vim --cmd 'profile start profile.log' \
    --cmd 'profile func *' \
    --cmd 'profile file *' \
    -c 'profdel func *' \
    -c 'profdel file *' \
    -c 'qa!'
```

You will get all timings in the profile.log. Table with function timings will be
present at the end of the file, to get per-script timings, use the following
script:

```
" Open profile.log file in vim first
let timings=[]
g/^SCRIPT/call add(timings, [getline('.')[len('SCRIPT  '):], matchstr(getline(line('.')+1), '^Sourced \zs\d\+')]+map(getline(line('.')+2, line('.')+3), 'matchstr(v:val, ''\d\+\.\d\+$'')'))
enew
call setline('.', ['count total (s)   self (s)  script']+map(copy(timings), 'printf("%5u %9s   %8s  %s", v:val[1], v:val[2], v:val[3], v:val[0])'))
```

This will open a new file containing just the same table as at the end of
profile.log, but 1) for scripts, not for functions, 2) unsorted.

If problem is your system, you may try the following:

1. When computer starts create a ram disk and mount it to ~/.vim, then copy all plugins there.
2. Try merging plugins into a single file, see `:h scriptmanager2#MergePluginFiles()` (vim-addon-manager must be activated)
3. Upgrade your computer
4. Try creating a hardlinks to all plugins in ~/.vim:

   ```
   cd ~/.vim/bundle;for d in *;do cd "$d";for f in **/*.vim;do t="$HOME/.vim/$(dirname "$f")";test -d "$t"||mkdir -p "$t";ln "$f" "$t";done;cd ..;done
   ```

Answer (score 2):

it might not be related, but for me the variable DISPLAY makes a big difference in the time it takes to start vim (even when I have vim compiled without gui).
Try with

```
DISPLAY= vim
```

and

```
DISPLAY=:0 vim
```

and see if you notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/R6E4czN7

### I've pasted the output of vim -V to pastebin (should be valid for 1 month). It's self explanatory. There are a gazillion searches(414 search lines - most of them are useless). I need to reduce the number of incorrect searches.

1297651453.71068: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/pathogen/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.71456: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/snipMate/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.71846: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/SuperTab/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.78737: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/surround/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.79179: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/taglist/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.79684: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/The_NERD_Commenter/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.80756: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/The_NERD_tree/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.83: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/tlib/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.86193: Searching for "/root/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-manager/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.8662: line 3: sourcing "/root/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-manager/autoload/scriptmanager.vim"[J
1297651453.88259: finished sourcing /root/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-manager/autoload/scriptmanager.vim[J

Comment: How did you record this timings?

Comment: You have something wrong with your system: 1) you should not normally work under root, 2) You have 414 searches that take 4.5 seconds (12 seconds for all initializations), but I have 805 searches and vim still loads normally in 0.7-0.8 seconds as I said. The only thing I could imagine to reduce number of searches is putting everything into ~/.vim directory.

Comment: Hi, timing: vim -V 1>&2|perl -MTime::HiRes=time -ne 'print time, ": ", $_' | tee vilog "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687799/profiling-vim-startup-time" It's kind of fixed: I edited /etc/vim/vimrc and inserted the following: autocmd SourcePre foo.vim set runtimepath=/usr/share/vim/vim71/
source /etc/vim/foo.vim
within foo.vim I have: autocmd SourcePre *vimrc set runtimepath=/usr/share/vim/vim71/
autocmd SourceCmd */indent.vim set runtimepath+=/root/.vim/ My home box where i noticed this problem is a Celeron 400MHz with an IDE disk :)

Comment: I have a computer with Celeron 600Hz and an IDE disk that works as a router, but I never tried to launch vim with all my plugins there. If I need some quick fixes, then I use vim with minimal setup, if I need some more editing, I either use sshfs or put everything under SCM. But in addition to suggestions that I made above you can try to keep all plugins in a separate directories, but on each plugin updates recursively create a hardlinks to them into ~/.vim (see script in updated answer).

Comment: @Paleywiener You'd be better off with using `vim -V 2> >( perl -MTime::HiRes=time -ne 'print time, ": ", $_' | tee vilog )` that will pipe stderr to your script without interruption stdout.  Your version didn't actually work for me at all.