# vim on virtualbox startup is slow when connected via putty

Tags: vim, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I am running freebsd on virtualbox (with virtualbox-ose-additions installed in freebsd).
the vim startup is very quick (instantaneous) in the vbox console window.
but when connected via putty from the host machine, the vim takes about 6-7 seconds to startup.
the connection from putty is via ssh authentication.
and the host to vbox connection is NAT+portforwarding.

Comment: Is this a specific vim issue or is this also the case for other terminal-based applications?

Comment: @Fredrick, i am seeing this problem only for vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened to me when I had `X11 Forwarding` turned on in Putty but didn't have an X Server running (always the case when using Putty from (I assume) Windows unless you're running specific software like Cygwin or Xming to have a local X Server).

Alternately, your shell startup scripts may set the `DISPLAY` environment variable improperly when you're ssh'd in instead of using a console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984335/vim-dynamic-runtimepath-per-module-vim-and-slow-startup/4988213#4988213 <-- this also works.

Comment: This is not just a Putty issue. Had this problem on OS X with the SSH connection being slow. Disabling X11 forwarding removed the sluggish connection.